# Determine the size of a block device

Tags: linux, size

How can I find out the size of a block device, such as `/dev/sda`? Running `ls -l` gives no useful information.

Comment: Understanding block size: http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Block_size

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`fdisk` doesn't understand the partition layout used by my Mac running Linux, nor any other non-PC partition format.  (Yes, there's `mac-fdisk` for old Mac partition tables, and `gdisk` for newer GPT partition table, but those aren't the only other partition layouts out there.)

Since the kernel already scanned the partition layouts when the block device came into service, why not ask it directly?

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8       16  390711384 sdb
   8       17     514079 sdb1
   8       18  390194752 sdb2
   8       32  976762584 sdc
   8       33     514079 sdc1
   8       34  976245952 sdc2
   8        0  156290904 sda
   8        1     514079 sda1
   8        2  155774272 sda2
   8       48 1465138584 sdd
   8       49     514079 sdd1
   8       50 1464621952 sdd2
```

Comment: This doesn't work for things like CD drives

Comment: And also only reports "native" names. On a server with iSCSI and/or multipath and/or LVM you get lots and lots of sd* and dm-* devices but usually you need to lookup the symlink of the one you're actually interested in (e.g.. a /dev/mapper/* one)

Comment: The values reported here are multiples of 1KiB which may be one sector (512 byte) too small.

Comment: This was useful to me. I ended up doing `awk '/sd[a-z]$/{printf "%s %8.2f GiB\n", $NF, $(NF-1) / 1024 / 1024}' /proc/partitions`

Answer (score 231):

`blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda` returns size in bytes.

`blockdev --getsz /dev/sda` returns size in 512-byte sectors.

Deprecated: `blockdev --getsize /dev/sda` returns size in sectors.

[**blockdev**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blockdev.8.html) is part of [util-linux](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/about/).

Comment: unfortunately needs superuser power

Comment: @heinrich5991 you have no choice. A normal user cannot access a block device directly ("raw reading" it), which is good for security.

Comment: @Totor Sure, but yet there are answers to this specific question that don't require any super user rights.

Comment: @heinrich5991 technically it's rather useless to know how big a block device is if you cannot even read it...

Comment: @Luke404 It's interesting when you can read and write to it indirectly (read: through a file system).

Comment: @heinrich5991 when working with filesystems you should ask statfs() and friends. More importantly, you should *not* assume any direct relationship between the block device size and total / usable / effective / free / whatever space on filesystem.

Comment: `blockdev --getsize` always is in units of 512 byte sectors, even if the device has 4K sectors.  Compare with `blockdev --report`

Comment: @Tino, how do you know? My manpage says nothing about `--getsize` always being 512 byte sectors.

Comment: If the specification isn't clear, then I guess the sector size for BLKGETSIZE  may effectively be implementation-defined.  You might be able to find some samples by searching the web or source code repos for "case BLKGETSIZE:".  There is some sample code in an O'Reilly book on device drivers that does not hard-code the sector size.

Comment: The manpage at https://linux.die.net/man/8/blockdev says `--getsize` is deprecated, and suggests `--getsz` for consistent 512-byte sectors.  If `--getsize` must be used, I guess `--getss` should also be used to make sure the sector size is what you expect.

Comment: It doesn't seem that `blockdev --getsize*` (and, probably, underlying BLKGETSIZE64 ioctl) requires superuser powers if the user has read permission for the disk device node:

```
# sudo -u user id
uid=314(user) gid=4000(eng) groups=4000(eng)
# ls -l hdw1
brw-rw---- 1 user disk 8, 177 Apr 10 17:17 hdw1
# sudo -u user blockdev --getsize64 hdw1
983040
# ls -l $(which blockdev)   # no setuid bit
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 26752 Dec 31  1999 /sbin/blockdev
```

Answer (score 47):

```
cat /sys/class/block/sda/size
```

This gives you its size in 512-byte blocks.

Comment: @heinrich5991 How can you be sure the device block-size is *always* 512 bytes?

Comment: The sector size is always 512 bytes according to [the source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/types.h?id=v4.4-rc6#n121). For the future, I am trying to get [this interface documented](https://lkml.kernel.org/r/1451154995-4686-1-git-send-email-peter@lekensteyn.nl).

Comment: Thank you for making that clear. I noticed that there's also a /sys/class/block/sda/queue/logical_block_size. I wasn't sure if I should use that, or the constant 512.

Comment: Usually compact disks have 2kB sectors. Adding hidden data, 2352 bytes.

Comment: Why Am I getting 500082032?

Answer (score 42):

This simple code.  Couldn't find *any* documentation, but does the trick nicely:

```c
#include <linux/fs.h>
...
ioctl(file, BLKGETSIZE64, &file_size_in_bytes);
```

Comment: Correction: it actually gets you the size in SECTORS. Edit it and I'll upvote.

Comment: @JCCyC: `BLKGETSIZE64` returns the size in bytes. See `linux/fs.h`, which notes "return device size in bytes". Note that `BLKGETSIZE` (no "64") returns it "/512".

Comment: I worked out a fuller sample partly based on this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48490543/446106.  To use the above snippet here, `file` needs to be a file descriptor (e.g. from `open()`), and `file_size_in_bytes` should be a `size_t`.

Comment: (Actually, `file_size_in_bytes` should be a 64-bit type, so it should be `unsigned long long`.)

Answer (score 27):

How about:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This will give you a list of all your disks with their respective capacity, usage, file system, and more.

Answer (score 25):

## Interactive use

```
lsblk -no SIZE /dev/block-device
```

Note that, if there are partitions, you get a list with the total size of the device followed by the size of each partition or you can append the partition to the device name.

## Scripting

If you need to store the size in a variable, use:

```
size=$(lsblk -bno SIZE /dev/path | head -1)
```

Now, the result is always in bytes and, if `path` does not include a partition, it is the total disk size, otherwise it is the partition size.

Answer (score 11):

`blockdev --getsize /dev/sda`

Comment: Use with `sudo`, otherwise you get `Permission denied`.

Answer (score 9):

```
echo "`cat /sys/class/block/sda2/size`*512" | bc
```

or if you use bash or any other POSIX-like shell whose arithmetic operators work with 64bit integers, you don't even need to call `bc`

```
echo "$((512*$(cat /sys/class/block/sda2/size)))"
```

gives the size in byte.

The call to `cat` and fork (except for `bash`) can be optimised away with `bash`, `ksh93` and `zsh` with:

```
echo "$((512*$(</sys/class/block/sda2/size)))"
```

Answer (score 7):

No need for ioctl in C. Just seek to the end of the file and get the size (in bytes) that way:

```c
/* define this before any #includes when dealing with large files: */
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// ...
int fd = open("/dev/sda", O_RDONLY);
off_t size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
// Now size is the size of the file, in bytes, or -1 on error.
// lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET) to get back to the start of the file.
```

Comment: If you're looking for the size of the raw disk drive, you'll need root privs to open the file to seek to the end.

Answer (score 5):

The blockdev(8) has a different answer? Options `--getsz` and deprecated `--getsize` are not the same.

- **BLKSSZGET** (`blockdev --getss`) is for physical sector size and
- **BLKBSZGET** (`blockdev --getbsz`) is for logical sector size.

```
echo $(($(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda)/$(blockdev --getss /dev/sda)))
```

Comment: Actually, I think you have those reversed.  (Unless my system has 512-byte physical blocks and 4096-byte logical blocks.)

Comment: Well, I realized that [`block/ioctl.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/ioctl.c) in Linux kernel source contains misleading comments. BLKPBSZGET (notice the P) gets physical sector size, BLKSSZGET gets logical sector size and BLKBSZGET (or BLKBSZGET_32 in `block/compat_ioctl.c`) gets file system allocation unit (cluster) size. [Logical and physical sector size differ when Advanced Format 512e is used.](http://www.oeey.com/2014/10/invalid-argument-directio-4kn.html) ([512e @ WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format#512e))

Comment: @Palec Most knowledgeful comment among all answers and comments to this question.

Answer (score 5):

First, my thanks to all who contributed. I learned a few
useful things.

Still, my experience is that most of these answers are somewhat
incomplete, at least where CD and DVDs are concerned,
notably regarding whether they are available to normal users
rather than restricted to the superuser.
This is based on tests on my Linux Mageia 2.

Commands intended for the superuser can always be accessed by a normal
user by prefixing them with `/sbin/`, or sometimes with /usr/sbin/.
Now they may or may not work for a normal user.

Many may work, for a normal user, for a DVD on the DVD drive, even
when it is not mounted, while they will not work for a hard disk
(again when invoked as normal user).

For example `/sbin/fdisk -l /dev/cdrom` will work on my system and
give the "geometry" of the DVD in the drive ... which is apparently
mostly nonsense.  But it does give the size of the DVD in bytes and in
sectors, and a correct sector size (of 2048 bytes as is usual for DVD).

The same is true of `/usr/sbin/gdisk -l /dev/cdrom`, which give only
the size in sectors of 2048 bytes.

other examples (as non-root, normal user)

```
$ /sbin/blockdev --getss /dev/cdrom   # DVD sector size
2048
$ /sbin/blockdev --getsize64 /dev/cdrom  # DVD byte size
5453316096

$ cat /proc/partitions  # see below
...
   8        8  416027241 sda8
  11        0    5325504 sr0
   8       16 1465138584 sdb
...
```

This works for the DVD drive, here called `sr0`, since the device for it
is actually `/dev/sr0`, `/dev/cdrom` being only a symbolic link to it.
The size is given in chunks of 1k.

Similarly, as normal user, the command

```
$ cat /sys/class/block/sr0/size
10651008
```

will give the size of a DVD on device `/dev/sr0`, in chunks of 512 bytes
(as well as the size of other disk, even not mounted).
However `cat /sys/class/block/cdrom/size` will not work be cause
/dev/cdrom is only a symbolic link

The command `df`, suggested by some, gives the size of mounted
partitions, not of whole disks. Furthermore, for a mounted CD or DVD
it gives less than the actual size of the CD/DVD. More precisely, there are
two distinct sizes one may be interested in :

- the overall size of the device, including what is used for its internal organization. Typically that is the size of the file obtained if it is copied whole with the command `dd`;
- the size of the space available (possibly only in read-only mode) to the user when it is mounted, which is always less. That is the size that is indicated by the command `df`.

Comment: uptick for $ /sbin/blockdev --getss /dev/cdrom   # DVD sector size

Comment: You say 512k but you mean just 512 byte sectors.

Answer (score 5):

A block is a sequence of bit or Bytes with a fixed length ie 512 bytes, 4kB, 8kB, 16kB, 32kB etc.

```
blockdev --getbsz partition
```

Example

```
# blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda1 
4096
```

So the block size of this file system is 4kB.

Analogy: number of bottles in crates.
[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Node.js, you can use this native add on to get block device size, physical sector size and logical sector size (with support for FreeBSD, Linux, macOS and Windows). It also has a few other helpers for doing direct IO:

https://github.com/ronomon/direct-io

Answer (score 1):

To show disks sizes in human readable form, type this as a simple user :

```
$ lsblk -do NAME,SIZE /dev/sd?
NAME      SIZE
sda       75G
sdb       200G
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `/sys/block/sda/size` in block size? If so which one?

The ioctl **BLKGETSIZE** has the same problem as it is in units of 512 rather than **BLKSSZGET**. **BLKGETSIZE64** solves this ambiguity. The real block count *is* **BLKGETSIZE64/BLKSSZGET**.

```
/*BINFMTC:
http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0105.2/0744.html
*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int fd;
        long blk=0L;
        long ssz=0L;
        long long oct=0LL;

        if((fd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY))<0) { perror(argv[1]); exit(1); }
        if(ioctl(fd,BLKGETSIZE,&blk)<0) { perror("BLKGETSIZE"); exit(1); }
        if(ioctl(fd,BLKSSZGET,&ssz)<0) { perror("BLKSSZGET"); exit(1); }
        if(ioctl(fd,BLKGETSIZE64,&oct)<0) { perror("BLKGETSIZE64"); exit(1); }
        if(close(fd)<0) { perror("close"); exit(1); }
        printf("BLKGETSIZE=%ld BLKSSZGET=%ld BLKGETSIZE64=%lld BLKGETSIZE64/BLKSSZGET=%ld SIZEGB=%f #%f\240GiB\n\n",\
blk,ssz,oct,(long)(oct/(long long)ssz),(double)oct/1000000000.0,(double)oct/1073741824.0);

        fflush(stdout); /* before exec */

        execl("/bin/bash","bash","-c",\
"for i in \
/sys/block/?d?/{size,alignment_offset,?d??/size,?d??/alignment_offset,queue/*block*,queue/*sector*}; \
do test -f \"$i\" && echo \"$i: $(<$i)\"; done"\
,NULL);

        exit(127);
        return 127; /* not reached */
}
```

See http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0105.2/0744.html

Comment: Abuse of assert:  If you disable assertions, your necessary side-effects won't happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is an EMC utility called `inq` which gives information about all types of block devices like local attached, SAN based, etc.

Try it out.

ftp://ftp.emc.com/pub/symm3000/inquiry/

Here is a brief description of what it does:
http://slashzeroconf.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/emc-inq-utility/

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "`blockdev --getbsz /dev/sdc`/1024"|bc
```

will show output in KB

```
[root@veritas datadg2]# echo "`blockdev --getbsz /dev/sdc`/1024"|bc
4
[root@veritas datadg2]#
```

Comment: bash can do calculations inline: `echo $(( $(blockdev ...)/1024 ))`. Also note, `--getbsz` gives the size of the block, not the size of the device.

Answer (score 0):

More simply:

`sudo parted -l /dev/sda`

Is for me the easiest to remember and type

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find it programmatically in C, checkout code of util-linux package - https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/lib/blkdev.c#L81

OR this is also useful - http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_20.html 
(The code works on Linux Kernel version `5.0.0-32-generic`.)

Both these codes use ioctl system call.

Answer (score -1):

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda | grep -m1 ^Disk | awk '{print $3 " " $4}'
```

I find it very useful than all those standard tools or proc entries

Answer (score -4):

```
df -k | grep /dev/sda
```

will give you the size in KB (first number) as well as the space used (second number) and space available (third number)

Comment: That's only if the filesystem is mounted.

Comment: This isn't about block device space, it will give you used and usable space of filesystems mounted that happen to be on /dev/sda. What about unpartitioned space? What if you have multiple partitions?