# How does lsblk obtain sector size?

Tags: lsblk

My disk is sda. There is the size file `/sys/dev/block/8:0/size`. Its unit is sectors. When I run `strace lsblk` I can see it reading this file.

But how does lsblk get the sector size to later show the total disk size in bytes?
Because I **cannot** see lsblk reading the file `hw_sector_size` nor `physical_block_size`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't because it doesn't need to, the sector size used in `/sys/block/<device>/size` is always 512 regardless of the actual physical sector size of the device. I wasn't able to find a documentation for this, so I'll refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52219/196468) which also has some [links to the kernel code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/include/linux/types.h#L125) in the comments where it is stated that

> Linux always considers sectors to be 512 bytes long independently of
> the devices real block size.

And a quick test with loop devices also shows that this is true:

```
$ cat /sys/block/loop0/size 
204800
$ cat /sys/block/loop0/queue/physical_block_size 
512

$ cat /sys/block/loop1/size 
204800
$ cat /sys/block/loop1/queue/physical_block_size 
4096
```

and these are both 100 MiB devices

```
$ lsblk
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                                           7:0    0   100M  0 loop  
loop1                                           7:1    0   100M  0 loop
```

(Note that if you ask `lsblk` to also include the physical sector size in the results using the `-o+PHY-SEC`, you can see it reads the `queue/physical_block_size` file when it actually needs the physical size.)

Comment: Indeed, in `lsblk.c:initialize_device` (ll. 1199-2000), one sees `if (ul_path_read_u64(dev->sysfs, &dev->size, "size") == 0) /* in sectors */
  dev->size <<= 9;     /* in bytes */
` with the sector size hardwired to 512 bytes.